# SQL convert datetime statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how do I convert the following SQL Statement into `ddmmyy` without has any delimiter?

```
convert(varchar(10), '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000', ??)
```

For example `2015-06-01 (yyyy-mm-dd)` want to convert as `010615 (ddmmyy)`.

Comment: Please mention which SQL server are you using?

Comment: Did any of the solution work?

Comment: @Empty : How about accepting an answer as the issue seems to be solved??

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Convert` function providing it with the style:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 5), '-', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this

```
SELECT (REPLACE(CONVERT(nchar(8), GETDATE(), 3), '/', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks, it was amazing!

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddMMyy')` 
Tested with MS SQL Server 2012. You can use a custom format of your choice.